# Gulp 4 browserSync in parallel with Pug and Parceljs Tasks in series

Tags: javascript, pug, gulp-browser-sync, gulp-4, parceljs

So basically what I'm trying to do is to make the browser refresh whenever there is a change in the files using **browserSync**, compiles **Pug** templates, then **Parceljs** does the bundling. And **Gulp** is to watch for changes.

The overall objective is a static website/page.

**The problem**:

If parcel fails building. browserSync exits. Watch stops.

```
[12:31:41] 'parcel' errored after 3.83 s
[12:31:41] Error in plugin "gulp-parcel"

[12:31:41] The following tasks did not complete: browserSync
[12:31:41] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

**OS**: Windows 10

Thanks!!

Gulpfile.js content:

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var parcel = require('gulp-parcel');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/templates/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/html'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('parcel', function () {
    return gulp.src('build/html/*.html', {
            read: false
        })
        .pipe(parcel())
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        },
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('browserSync',gulp.series('html', 'parcel')), function () {
    gulp.watch('src/templates/**/*.pug', gulp.series('html', 'parcel'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'), function(){
    console.log('Started default');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a bit, the **gulp-parcel** plugin had a bug which is still being worked on. Meanwhile, I was able to come up with a workaround.

- Upgraded to es6
- Implemented '**gulp-run-command'** to run Parcel in watch mode

Here is my new solution:

```
'use strict';

import gulp from 'gulp';
import babel from 'gulp-babel';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import run from 'gulp-run-command';
import log from 'fancy-log';
import errorHandler from 'gulp-error-handle';


const server = browserSync.create();


const paths = {
    parcel: {
        dist: 'dist/*'
    }
};

gulp.task('parcel', run('parcel watch src/templates/index.pug --public-url ./ --no-cache'));

const reload = done => {
    server.reload();
    done();
};

const serve = done => {
    server.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist/'
        }
    });
    done();
};

const watch = done => {
    gulp.watch(paths.parcel.dist, gulp.series(reload));
    done();
};

const dev = gulp.parallel('parcel', serve, watch);
export default dev;
```